# Java Spring REST API Status 400 response on POST / PUT

Tags: java, spring, rest, fetch-api

I built a REST API Service using Java Spring Cloud / Boot. Firstly, I made a simple class connected to a MongoDB and a controller with service that should allow me to add, delete, update and get all the objects. When using POSTMAN these all work, however when I want to add or update an object using redux and fetch API I get a status 400 and "bad request" error. This seems to have something to do with the JSON I'm sending in the body but it is the exact same format of JSON that is working with for example POSTMAN.

My action in Redux. For simplicity / test purposes I added an object at the top in stead of using the object being sent from the page.

```
var assetObject = {
  "vendor" : "why dis no work?",
  "name": "wtf",
  "version": "231",
  "category" : "qsd",
  "technology" : "whatever"
}

export function addAsset(access_token, asset) {
  return dispatch => {
    fetch(constants.SERVER_ADDRESS + '/as/asset/add',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer' + access_token,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: assetObject
      })
      .then(res => dispatch({
        type: constants.ADD_ASSET,
        asset
      }))
  }
}
```

Controller code in Java Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/add")
public void addAsset(@RequestBody Asset asset) {
    assetService.addAsset(asset);
}
```

Status ok while doing it in postman:

[image: postman request]

The error I get when using Redux / Fetch API (I only removed the directory structure because it has company name in it):

[image: request error in browser]

Have been stuck on this for a while, any help is much appreciated!

EDIT Asset Object:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "assets")
public class Asset {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String vendor;
    private String name;
    private String version;
    private String category;
    private String technology;

    public Asset() {
    }

    public Asset(String id,
                 String vendor,
                 String name,
                 String version,
                 String category,
                 String technology) {
        this.id = id;
        this.vendor = vendor;
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
        this.category = category;
        this.technology = technology;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getVendor() {
        return vendor;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public String getTechnology() {
        return technology;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setVendor(String vendor) {
        this.vendor = vendor;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public void setTechnology(String technology) {
        this.technology = technology;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you copy / paste your Asset java object ?

Comment: you are missing the ID in your json, thus getting 400. Could you try and tell me the result ?

Comment: No it doesn't really matter, If I don't give an id, mongoDB just creates one.

Comment: To me, it seems like Spring is rejecting your request because it cannot fit your json into your object because you did not provider any ID field in your json

Comment: Adding the ID doesn't make any difference + using Postman I can add the object, even if I don't even add the attribute 'id'. Because it works in Postman it most probably has something to do with the Fetch API .. but I'm not sure.

Comment: Not sure how exactly fetch API works. Did you try formatting the body to json? body: JSON.stringify(assetObject)?

Comment: Ok so adding JSON.stringify() solved the problem! If you can add it as an answer I can give you the rep

Answer (score 2):

your error message says :

> ; required request body is missing

i think the error happens when your `controller` method
trying to form an object from the incoming request.

when you are sending the request you have to `set` each and every field related to the object.
if you are planning on not setting a property you should mark that field with `@JsonIgnore` annotation.

you can use `@JsonIgnore`  annotation on the variable  which will ignore this property 
when forming the object as well as when outputing the object.

use `@JsonIgnore`  annotation on the `setter method` , which i think you should do now since
you are ignoring the `id property` when making the request.

```
@JsonIgnore 
public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
}
```

and you can return `httpstatus` code from the `controller method`,
so that client knows request was successful

```
@ResponseBody 
public ResponseEntity<String> addAsset(@RequestBody Asset asset) {
return new ResponseEntity<String>("your response here", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```